# Executing function in child component from parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm using React Native, and I have a functional component that has a function in it.
This child component is located inside another component, on that another component I have a button.
So, When the user clicks the button, I want to execute the function in the child component.

I read about forwardRef (as I saw few questions about this that suggested this solution): https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html
But it does not seems to fit my problem.
I don't need to access an element in my child component, only to execute the function.

This is my child component:

```
  const Popup = () => {
  const opacity = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const translationY = useRef(new Animated.Value(-120)).current;

  const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext);

  const displayPopup = () => {
    Animated.spring(translationY, {
      toValue: 100,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={[
        styles.container,
        {
          backgroundColor: theme.popup,
          opacity: opacity,
          transform: [{translateY: translationY}],
        },
      ]}>
     ...
    </Animated.View>
  );
};
```

Inside the parent component:

```
<SafeAreaView>
      // Other components
      <Popup />
      <Button onPress={() => {//NEEDS TO CALL displayPopup}}/>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: This sounds like it is incorrectly designed. Parents can pass methods to children for them to call, but you shouldn't call child methods from parents.

Comment: note you are using [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) incorrectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a forward ref to give access to a child function can be a solution, but it's not the React way to do it (See [useImperativeHandle hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle))

Instead, I would change a props of the Popup component to trigger the animation you want to use:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

 const Popup = ({display = false}) => {
  const opacity = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const translationY = useRef(new Animated.Value(-120)).current;

  const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext);

  useEffect(() => {
      if(display){
        Animated.spring(translationY, {
            toValue: 100,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
      } 
  }, [display])

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={[
        styles.container,
        {
          backgroundColor: theme.popup,
          opacity: opacity,
          transform: [{translateY: translationY}],
        },
      ]}>
     ...
    </Animated.View>
  );
};
```

Parent component:

```
const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);

return(
   <SafeAreaView>
      // Other components
      <Popup display={display} />
      <Button onPress={() => {setDisplay(true)}}/>
    </SafeAreaView> 
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working great for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `ref` forward it to the child component and use [`useImparativeHandle`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) in the child to augment the ref so that the parent can invoke it.

Just run this code snippet:

```js
const { useState, useRef, createRef, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } = React;

const TextInput = forwardRef(({value, otherProps}, ref) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(value || "");

  const clearText = () => setText("");

  // augment the ref by adding the clearText function
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    clearText
  }));

  return (
    <input ref={ref} type="text" onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
       value={text} {...otherProps}
    />
  );
});

const Parent = () => {
  const textRef = createRef();
  const onClickButton = () => textRef.current.clearText();

  return (
    <div>
      <TextInput ref={textRef} value="Enter Text" />
      <button onClick={() => onClickButton()}>Clear Text</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

As the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) states

> As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases.

and later they say

> In this example, a parent component that renders  would be able to call inputRef.current.focus().

It's up to you to decide if your code is one of the few cases in which it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about useImparativeHandle. I guess I should read more about this hook.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `Animated.value` in the parent component and put it in the props of child component:

```jsx
const Parent = () => {
  const translationY = useRef(new Animated.Value(-120)).current;

  const displayPopup = useCallback(() => {
    Animated.spring(translationY, {
      toValue: 100,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, [translationY]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Popup translationY={translationY}/>
      <Button onPress={displayPopup}/>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const Popup = ({translationY}) => {
  const opacity = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={[
        styles.container,
        {
          backgroundColor: theme.popup,
          opacity: opacity,
          transform: [{translateY: translationY}],
        },
      ]}>
       ...
    </Animated.View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this is something I will do if I won't find a solution. I tried to avoid this because my parent component is already pretty messy.